# Unpublish Instant App APK while keeping main APK published

Tags: google-developers-console, android-instant-apps

I've been getting a 'We will soon take action because your app does not adhere to Google Play Developer Program policies. Fix violations as soon as possible.' warning because an old Instant App APK that was tied to my main app is sdk version 31, not 33, and apps have to target the current sdk version. There seems no way to delete or unpublish just this old package 967, which is apparently threatening the unpublishing of my main package 2218 in a couple days.

[image]

[image]